# Background-color of a ul not expanding to overflow:auto

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow, background-color

I have a `ul` contained within a `div` given a specific width and height, and set to `overflow: auto`. Where the text is visible, the `background-color` is filling the area correctly:

[image]

...*however*, when the scrolled-area is shown, the `background-color` does **not** expand to the overflow area:

[image]

---

Here is the CSS:

```
.list_container {
    height: 145px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;

    /* for horizontal scrollbar: */
    overflow: auto;

    /* to prevent text from wrapping: */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    #list {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;

        /* getting rid of list styling: */
        list-style-type: none;
    }
        /* getting rid of browser list indenting: */
        #list, #list li {
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
        }
```

...and the HTML:

```
<div class = "list_container">
    <ul id = "list">
        <li>asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</li>
        <li>qwerty qwerty qwerty qwerty</li>
        <li>123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123</li>
        <li>abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `background-color` on the `list-container` not on the `ul`.

```
.list_container {
    height: 145px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid black;

    /* for horizontal scrollbar: */
    overflow: auto;

    /* to prevent text from wrapping: */
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
#list {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 100%;
}
#list, #list li {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/JY8J7/)

#### The problem:

Your `ul` has a shorter width so the `background-color` is applied on the shorter part of the container div. But when you put the `background-color` on the container it fills whole of it's width.

Comment: Oh ha -- didn't try that, thanks @Mohammad! How might I add a `background-color` to a single `li` without the same problem?